# $p^3 = 2009 + 47 * 2^q$ where p and q are primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

> Solve the ecuations $p^3 = 2009 + 47 * 2^q$, where $p$ and $q$ are
>   primes.

Fermat's little theorem could help.

Comment: $q=2$ is the only solution.

Comment: @Lucian figure out that, but how can I proof that is the *only* one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**  Assume that $q\geq 5$ then $q$ is either of the form $6k+1$ or $6k-1$, taking the equation modulo $9$ gives us :
 $$2^{q}\equiv 2 \pmod 9 \text{ or } 2^{q}\equiv 5 \pmod 9 $$
hence $p^3\equiv \{6,3\}\pmod 9$ , but both cases are incompatible with the fact that for every integer $n$ we have  :
 $$n^3\equiv \{0,1,-1\} \pmod 9 $$

(**Notation** I used $x\equiv \{a,b,\cdots\} \mod 9$ to say that $x\equiv a\mod 9$ or $x\equiv b \mod 9$ or $x\equiv \cdots \mod 9$)

Comment: Very nice. In particular it is not used the fact that $p$ is a prime number.